# Best way to set "Content-Type" header in HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

In my program I am generating a custom `HttpWebRequest` based off of the following JSON schema:

```
{
    "Endpoint": "String",
    "Method": "String",
    "Headers": [
       {
           "Name": "String",
           "Value": "String"
       }
    ]
}
```

And the code below loops through each `Header` and adds it to the `HttpWebRequest`

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Endpoint);
foreach (var item in Headers)
{
    request.Headers.Add(item.Name, item.Value);
}
```

This works for most custom headers, but I came across the problem of setting the `ContentType` header. Since that specific header cannot be added in by the above method, I devised a way, using `Reflection` to set the `request`'s `ContentType` property.

```
public static void SetHeaderValue(this HttpWebRequest request, string headerName, string headerValue)
{
    Type type = typeof(HttpWebRequest);
    PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(headerName);
    if (prop != null)
    {
        prop.SetValue(request, headerValue);
    }
}
```

My question is this: Is using `Reflection` the best way to approach this, or even a safe way to approach solving this problem?

Comment: Umm using the setter.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.contenttype?view=netframework-4.8, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection gives you the most compact code. But it's definitely not the fastest and probably not the most intuitive way to do it. Perhaps it makes sense to explicitly list all standard headers and populate them using a property setter:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Endpoint);
foreach (var item in Headers)
{
    string headerName = item.Name.ToLower();
    switch (headerName)
    {
        case "contenttype": request.ContentType = item.Value; break;
        case "accept": request.Accept = item.Value; break;
        case "useragent": request.UserAgent = item.Value; break;
        // ... other standard headers
        default:
            // set custom header as usual
            request.Headers.Add(item.Name, item.Value);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reflection sounds like a bad idea, it is fragile (ish, they *probably* won't change the internals) but you are working against the design. *I've always thought this design of hiding 'special' values was wrong though*

I'd go with a map or as above a switch. You can inject a map in if you want tests.

```cs
// textarea code, might not compile

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Endpoint);
var special = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>{
    ["contenttype"] = v => request.ContentType = v,
    ["accept"] = v => request.Accept = v,
    ["useragent"] = v => request.UserAgent = v,
};
foreach (var item in Headers)
{
    special.TryGetValue(item.Name.ToLower(), out var fn) ?
        fn(item.Value) :
        request.Headers.Add(item.Name, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: It's also an option. But firstly you forgot `new` keyword and secondly you'll get a `KeyNotFoundException`: it's better to use something like `special.ContainsKey(item.Name.ToLower())`

Comment: @RomanKoliada , `new` was missing, `ContainsKey` would not be as good as `TryGetValue` so I fixed that.